# How to uninstall angular/cli version 11.0.2 to be possible to reinstall angular/cli version 10.0.0 ? (I need this for PrimeNG with ng v10.0.0)

Tags: primeng, angular10, angular11

Usual methods doesn't work.

I need this down-version to be possible to use PrimeNG, which looks like doesn't fixed all error to latest version of ng v11.0.2

I already try all these options from below. Nothing works.

Also what is on angular website v 11.0.2 documentation to unistall @angular/cli also doesn't work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/11.0.2

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli  
npm cache verify  
 if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean`  
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

I need to use this one after uninstall:
npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.0

When I do all this steps the **ng v**  shows the same 11.0.2 version.

I tried and old methods but doesn't work.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm cache verify   
npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.0  
npm install
```

No sequence work:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm cache clean 
npm cache clean --force 
npm cache verify
```

Any new idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the uninstall and reinstall without the global flag. You want to uninstall it in your specific project, not globally here.

If that does not work, if your project is tracked by git or local changes, you can find the versions you were using and manually update your `package.json` with these versions, and then run `npm i` on your project.

If you need primeNg version to be compatible, they have version `11.0.0-rc1` and will soon be coming out with the non rc version